# Java card game. (Game of War)

Tags: java, arraylist, playing-cards

So I have have to implement the card game War. I have it all going well except for my loop stops when it hits the size of one of the decks (arraylist). What I want it to do is loop until one of the decks is empty. And pointers on how I can do that? I understand my code could be shortened, but I don't need to worry about that right now. Here is my code:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;

public class lab9_11{
    public static void main(String args[]){

        System.out.printf("\n");
        System.out.printf("\n");
        System.out.printf("\\         / /\\   |\\  |\n");
        System.out.printf(" \\  / \\  / /__\\  |/  |\n");
        System.out.printf("  \\/   \\/ /    \\ |\\  o\n");
        System.out.printf("\n");
        System.out.printf("Lets play a game of war.\n");
        System.out.printf("Type 1 to begin or 0 to exit.\n");
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in); 

        int initial = keyboard.nextInt();

        if (initial > 1){
            System.out.printf("You can't read, so you shouldn't play this.\n");
            System.exit(-1);
        }

        if (initial == 0){
            System.exit(-1);
        }

        else {
            System.out.printf("Okay, lets play!\n");
            System.out.printf("\n");
        }
        System.out.printf("Here is a deck of 52 cards -> []:\n");

        int deck[] = new int[52];

        deck[0] = 2; //0-12 = hearts
        deck[1] = 3;
        deck[2] = 4;
        deck[3] = 5;
        deck[4] = 6;
        deck[5] = 7;
        deck[6] = 8;
        deck[7] = 9;
        deck[8] = 10;
        deck[9] = 11; //jack of hearts
        deck[10] = 12; //queen of hearts 
        deck[11] = 13; //king of hearts
        deck[12] = 14; //ace of hearts

        deck[13] = 2; //13-25 = spades
        deck[14] = 3;
        deck[15] = 4;
        deck[16] = 5;
        deck[17] = 6;
        deck[18] = 7;
        deck[19] = 8;
        deck[20] = 9;
        deck[21] = 10;
        deck[22] = 11; //jack of spades
        deck[23] = 12; //queen of spades 
        deck[24] = 13; //king of spades
        deck[25] = 14; //ace of spades

        deck[26] = 2; //0-12 = diamonds
        deck[27] = 3;
        deck[28] = 4;
        deck[29] = 5;
        deck[30] = 6;
        deck[31] = 7;
        deck[32] = 8;
        deck[33] = 9;
        deck[34] = 10;
        deck[35] = 11; //jack of diamonds
        deck[36] = 12; //queen of diamonds 
        deck[37] = 13; //king of diamonds
        deck[38] = 14; //ace of diamonds

        deck[39] = 2; //39-51 = clubs
        deck[40] = 3;
        deck[41] = 4;
        deck[42] = 5;
        deck[43] = 6;
        deck[44] = 7;
        deck[45] = 8;
        deck[46] = 9;
        deck[47] = 10;
        deck[48] = 11; //jack of clubs
        deck[49] = 12; //queen of clubs 
        deck[50] = 13; //king of clubs
        deck[51] = 14; //ace of clubs

        System.out.printf("First, lets shuffle it into 2 decks of 26.\n");

        Random rangen = new Random(); //Random number generator
        for (int i=0; i < deck.length; i++) { //shuffles the deck
            int randomPosition = rangen.nextInt(deck.length);
            int temp = deck[i];
            deck[i] = deck[randomPosition];
            deck[randomPosition] = temp;
        }

        int[] player1 = new int[26]; //initializes 1st player's deck
        int[] player2 = new int[26]; //initializes 2nd player's deck

        System.arraycopy(deck, 0, player1, 0, player1.length); //takes 26 cards and puts into player1's deck.
        System.arraycopy(deck, player1.length, player2, 0, player2.length);//takes the other 26 and puts into player2's deck.
        System.out.printf(".\n");
        System.out.printf(".\n");
        System.out.printf("Here's your deck. --> [?]\n");
        System.out.printf(".\n");
        System.out.printf(".\n");
        System.out.printf("Here's your opponent's deck. --> [?]\n");
        System.out.printf(".\n");
        System.out.printf(".\n");
        System.out.printf("Okay, lets begin!\n");
        System.out.printf("\n");
        System.out.printf("\n");
        System.out.printf("Type 1 to flip your cards.\n");
        System.out.printf("Which ever player holds all the cards by the end wins.\n");
        int q = keyboard.nextInt();
        if (q == 1){
            System.out.printf("Lets see...\n");
        }
        if (q != 1){
            System.out.printf("That wasn't one... type the number '1' or else the game will end because you are stupid.\n");
            int q2 = keyboard.nextInt();
                if (q != 1) {
                System.exit(-1);
            }       
        }
        List<Integer> player1List = new ArrayList<Integer>();//converts array1 into arraylist1
        for (int i = 0; i < player1.length; i++)
        {
            player1List.add(player1[i]);
        }
        System.out.println(player1List);
        List<Integer> player2List = new ArrayList<Integer>();//converts array2 into arraylist2
        for (int i = 0; i < player2.length; i++)
        {
            player2List.add(player2[i]);
        }
        System.out.println(player2List);


        for (int i = 0; i < player1List.size(); i++){
            if (player1List.get(i) < player2List.get(i)){
                System.out.printf("Player 1: %d\n", player1List.get(i));
                System.out.printf("Player 2: %d\n", player2List.get(i));
                System.out.printf("Player 2 wins round!\n");
                player2List.add(player1List.get(i));
                player1List.remove(player1List.get(i));
            }
            if (player1List.get(i) < player2List.get(i)){
                System.out.printf("Player 1: %d\n", player1List.get(i));
                System.out.printf("Player 2: %d\n", player2List.get(i));
                System.out.printf("Player 1 wins round!\n");
                player1List.add(player2List.get(i));
                player2List.remove(player2List.get(i));
            }
            if (player1List.get(i) == player2List.get(i)){
                System.out.printf("Player 1: %d\n", player1List.get(i));
                System.out.printf("Player 2: %d\n", player2List.get(i));
                System.out.printf("It's a tie, cards return to your deck.\n");
            }
        }
        if (player1List.isEmpty() || player2List.isEmpty()){
            if (player1List.isEmpty()) {
                System.out.printf("Player 2 WINS THE GAME!!!!!!\n");
            }
            if (player2List.isEmpty()) {
                System.out.printf("Player 1 WINS THE GAME!!!!!!\n");
            }
        }


        System.out.println(player1List);

        System.out.println(player2List);


        /*
        System.out.printf("test.\n");
        System.out.printf("test1111.\n");
        for(int i = 0; i < player1.length; i++){
            System.out.println(player1[i]);
        }
        System.out.printf("test.\n");
        System.out.printf("test222.\n");
        for(int i = 0; i < player2.length; i++){
            System.out.println(player2[i]);
        }
        System.out.printf("test.\n");
        System.out.printf("test11.\n");
        for(int i = 0; i < win1.length; i++){
            System.out.println(win1[i]);
        }
        System.out.printf("test.\n");
        System.out.printf("test22.\n");
        for(int i = 0; i < win2.length; i++){
            System.out.println(win2[i]);
        }
        */

        System.out.printf("\n");
        System.out.printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Here is my for loop narrowed down. I need it so it loops until one of the arraylists is empty.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < player1List.size(); i++){
        if (player1List.get(i) < player2List.get(i)){
            System.out.printf("Player 1: %d\n", player1List.get(i));
            System.out.printf("Player 2: %d\n", player2List.get(i));
            System.out.printf("Player 2 wins round!\n");
            player2List.add(player1List.get(i));
            player1List.remove(player1List.get(i));
        }
        if (player1List.get(i) < player2List.get(i)){
            System.out.printf("Player 1: %d\n", player1List.get(i));
            System.out.printf("Player 2: %d\n", player2List.get(i));
            System.out.printf("Player 1 wins round!\n");
            player1List.add(player2List.get(i));
            player2List.remove(player2List.get(i));
        }
        if (player1List.get(i) == player2List.get(i)){
            System.out.printf("Player 1: %d\n", player1List.get(i));
            System.out.printf("Player 2: %d\n", player2List.get(i));
            System.out.printf("It's a tie, cards return to your deck.\n");
        }
    }
    if (player1List.isEmpty() || player2List.isEmpty()){
        if (player1List.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.printf("Player 2 WINS THE GAME!!!!!!\n");
        }
        if (player2List.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.printf("Player 1 WINS THE GAME!!!!!!\n");
        }
    }
```

Comment: I've added the homework tag because this looks a lot like homework.  If that's not the case, feel free to remove the tag.

Comment: ugly code, break up into more methods.

Comment: I know, this is just my base for the program. Clean up will be after.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using a [Queue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html) for your decks, as you need to put (*offer*) cards on one side of the deck (the bottom) and retrieve (*poll*) cards from the top (as far as I understand from the Wikipedia entry about this game). A `LinkedList` is a good implementation of a `Queue`. The code could go something like this:

```
while(!deck1.isEmpty() && !deck2.isEmpty()) {
    int card1 = deck1.poll();
    int card2 = deck2.poll();

    if(card1 < card2) {
        deck2.offer(card2);
        deck2.offer(card1);
    }

    if(card2 < card1) {
        deck1.offer(card1);
        deck1.offer(card2);
    }

    if(card1 == card2) {
        deck1.offer(card1);
        deck2.offer(card2);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem you are experiencing is due to you changing the ArrayList you are iterating around.

eg.

```
for (int i = 0; i < player1List.size(); i++){

  player1List.remove(i);

}
```

In the above code, upon entering the loop, `i` is set to `0`, and player1List.size() returns `2` - so the loop is entered.
During this loop, an element is removed from the ArrayList, and upon checking for the 2nd iteration of the loop, player1List.size() now returns `1` (since an element was removed) this then fails the loop check, and it does not go round a second time.

You need to find an approach which does not involve changing the List you are iterating over. (perhaps `clone()` it? or maybe copy the elements into a temporary array?)

HTH

Answer (score 0):

hey you have to use two counters, instead of one
for (int i = 0; i < player1List.size(); i++) //with one counter you can't predict whose cards ended!
for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < player1List.size() && j < player2List.size(); i++, j++)//like this

another mistake is:  if (player1List.get(i) < player2List.get(i)) //second if condition of for loop